# How to get the hashmap values?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

Im new to android..

I have  three ArrayList hashmap..one is for questions, second is for question id and third is for answers..

I got the questions and question id and answers in JSON object..  Now i want to display the question and answers...What i need is,
I have three ArrayList. QtnsArraylist1(ques1) contains 100 elements(100 questions) and QuestidArraylist contains 100 id's and AnsArraylist2(answ1) contains 400 elements( 400 Answers, for each question 4 options totally 400 elements). I want to get these values from hashmap..

For my first Question in QtnsArraylist1(ques1) i have to get first 4 elements from AnsArraylist2(answ1) based upon the hashmap key questionid.Similarly if i give next button it display for question 2,3,4... .These all should do in onPostExecute() How i can get this?

Thanks in advance..

> ```
>   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>         pDialog.dismiss();       
>         ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(ques1));
>         System.out.println(" Question array:"+ques1);
>         String[] quesArr = new String [ques1.size()];
>         quesArr = ques1.toArray(quesArr);
>         for(String s: quesArr){
>             System.out.println("All Array Questions:"+s);
>             final TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
>             final String text=ques1.get(j).toString();
>             System.out.println("Array:"+text);
>             txtque.setText(text);
>         }            
>         answ1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(answ1));
>         System.out.println(" Answer array:"+answ1);
>         String[] answArr = new String [answ1.size()];
>         answArr = answ1.toArray(answArr);
>         for(String A: answArr){
>             // final Object getName0 = answArr[0].toString();
>             // final Object getName1 = answArr[1].toString();
>             // final Object getName2 = answArr[2].toString();
>             // final Object getName3 = answArr[3].toString();
>             Collections.sort(answ1, new Comparator<String>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
>                     return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
>                 }
>             });
>         System.out.println("All Array Answers:"+A);    
>         }                 
>         btn_practicerg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgroup);
>         btn_practice1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB1);
>         btn_practice1.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[0]));
>         btn_practice2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB2);
>         btn_practice2.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[1]));
>         btn_practice3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB3);
>         btn_practice3.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[2]));
>         btn_practice4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB4);
>         btn_practice4.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[3]));              
>         Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
>         nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>             public void onClick(View v){
>             j++;
>             TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
>             txtque.setText(ques1.get(j).toString());                               
>             k++;
>             btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
>             k++;
>             btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
>             k++;
>             btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
>             k++;
>             btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
> ```

Comment: Post some code, please - I can't figure out what you have - `HashMap` or `ArrayList`.

Comment: I cannot see `HashMap` in your code, only `HashSet`.

Comment: yes I want to use hashmap and get the values how to use and get it..by my arraylist please help me..

Comment: Excuse me - it's total chaos. Describe the task to want to achieve: How many questions and answers you want to display, which one, where are the data coming from, what data structure you have (declaration and initialization of quest1 and answ1)

Comment: @GaborSch see my full code here http://pastebin.com/b4rKEwGN please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your answer as HashMap in an Arraylist. That would make all your ArrayList of same size.

For instance,

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("1", "abc");
hm.put("2", "def");
hm.put("3", "ghi");
hm.put("4", "jkl");

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lstAns = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
lstAns.add(hm);
```

To access answers:

```
System.out.println("answer1 " + lstAns.get(index).get("1")); // gives "abc"
```

Comment: i want take the answers base upon question id i used json...how implement hashmap for this...not by static..see my full code here http://pastebin.com/b4rKEwGN

Comment: post some sample JSON strings too.